# Is there any CDK or CloudFormation support for Container Recipes in AWS Image Builder?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I don't see any resource for Container Recipes for AWS Image Builder in the [CDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/aws-imagebuilder-readme.html) or [CloudFormation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/AWS_ImageBuilder.html) documentation.

The closest thing I can find is support for Image Recipes, with is not used for creating container images, only AMIs. I am really needing to add this resource to my CF stack to create a image(as in a container image) pipeline that pushes the resulting image into ECR... which I CAN do manually, only.. so far.

I'm using the TS CDK lib, not that it matters atm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In cloudformation there is [AWS::ImageBuilder::ContainerRecipe](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-imagebuilder-containerrecipe.html):

> Creates a **new container recipe**. Container recipes define how images are configured, tested, and assessed.

The docs also provide [example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-imagebuilder-containerrecipe.html#aws-resource-imagebuilder-containerrecipe--examples) how to create a container recipe. Thus its not clear from you question, if you expect different type of container recopies to be created in CloudFormation?

Example from docs:

```
Resources:
   ContainerRecipeAllParameters:
      Type: 'AWS::ImageBuilder::ContainerRecipe'
      Properties:
         Name: 'container-recipe-name'
         Version: '1.0.0'
         ParentImage: !Ref ParentImage
         Description: 'description'
         ContainerType: 'DOCKER'
         Components:
            - ComponentArn: !Ref ComponentArn
            - ComponentArn: !Ref AnotherComponentArn
         TargetRepository:
            Service: 'ECR'
            RepositoryName: !Ref RepositoryName
         DockerfileTemplateData: |
           FROM {{{ imagebuilder:parentImage }}}
           {{{ imagebuilder:environments }}}
           {{{ imagebuilder:components }}}
         WorkingDirectory: "dummy-working-directory"
         KmsKeyId: !Ref KmsKeyId
         Tags:
            Usage: 'Documentation'
```

Comment: idk if the AWS::ImageBuilder::ContainerRecipe resource is new or I just didn't see it, but i swear it wasn't an option at the time I posted this... or maybe it was lol... idk

Comment: @aphexlog Not sure if its new or not. Maybe CFN resources have similar names, so it could be just a case as simple as overlooking it.